# SNAP Apps not launching

Tags: software-installation, snap

Recently i tried launching all my snap apps.However its not opening. So I tried run telegram snap app in terminal (sudo snap run telegram-desktop).But i got the below issue. I am using Ubuntu 18.04
[image]

Comment: For someone wanting to look into the issue, it is difficult to try reproducing the issue with the limited information you provide.

Comment: Can you please help what information should i need to add. Should i need to add any log.